# How can send html text box value with Url.Action to controller action method input argument?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new in asp.net mvc and want to read html text box value and send it to the controller action method argument,for that purpose in view page write this code:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Item", "Store", new {parentPartId = @item.Id,UserID=12})">@item.BookName</a>
```

in `url action` in this segment:
UserID=html text box value

 read value and send it to this action in controller:

```
public ActionResult Item(int parentPartId,int UserID)
        {
}
```

in view page my text box is this:

```
<input type="text" id="USERID"/>
```

How can i solve that problem?thanks.

Comment: option 1: put the textbox into a form, and have the user submit the form (via a button probably), whose "action" would point to the Action method you mentioned. This would cause the value in the textbox to be passed as an argument to the controller. You'd have to make sure the textbox name matches the paramter name. option 2: use some javascript to collect the value of the textbox when the user clicks on the link. Use that to place the value into the URL before you allow the link to trigger.

Comment: @ADyson How can i use the option 2?

Comment: Don't directly set a href on the link. handle its click event. use preventDefault to stop normal redirect behaviour. Create a variable containing the value of the Url.Action helper, except change `@item.Id` to a placeholder string, such as "PARENT_ID". Get the generated URL and use string replace function to switch PARENT_ID with the value from the textbox. Then redirect user to this newly generated URL.

Comment: @ADyson Can you write me code?

Comment: these are all standard basic tasks in javascript but OK I will give you an example.

Comment: @ADyson I understand you. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle the click event of the hyperlink and inject the value from the textbox into it, like this:

HTML:

```
<a class="BookName" href="" data-id="@item.Id">@item.BookName</a>
```

Script (assumes you have jQuery, but easily re-writable if not):

```
$(".BookName").click(function(event)
{
  event.preventDefault();
  var url = '@Url.Action("Item", "Store", new {parentPartId = "PARENT_ID",UserID="USER_ID"})';
  url = url.replace("USER_ID", $("#USERID").val());
  url = url.replace("PARENT_ID", $(this).data("id"));
alert(url); //just for debugging
  window.location.href = url;
});
```

You might want to check the input value is valid before you do this, but this will get you started.

Comment: thanks,i run that and get this error:The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'UserID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Item(Int32, Int32)' in 'StoreProject.Controllers.StoreController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: @behibehi did you definitely write a number in the USERID textbox before clicking? I have inserted an `alert` into the code so we can check that the URL looks right before submitting, perhaps if there's a problem it would be good to post the output of this here so we can check it.

Comment: Console output is:/Store/Item?parentPartId=1&amp;UserID=

Comment: @OzanErtürk what on earth does "infertile" mean in the context of programming? I have no idea what you are getting at.

Comment: @ADyson yes the USERID textBox has a number value before click

Comment: if you insert `alert($("#USERID").val());` into the function, what does it output? I assume your textbox looks like the one in your example (i.e. it must have an ID of "USERID")?

Comment: You are creating dynamic javascript code that will generally create a maintain problem. This is a job to handle on the client side. Let javascript to do that. you should separate the works and this is a client side work.

Comment: @ADyson and it means "inefficient" sorry for my english.

Comment: @ADyson and I thought you vote my answer with no reason.

Comment: @ADyson i think amp; is inCorrect in URL

Comment: @OzanErtürk your solution is also client-side. All code requires maintenance. I fail to see the difference, except that yours uses outdated ways to declare event listeners, arbitrarily mixes jQuery and standard JS syntax, and fails to generate the required URL in a robust way. You also use a POST request when a hyperlink would be a GET, and don't reproduce the same behaviour as required by the OP (redirect vs ajax request).

Comment: behibehi I agree, this is odd, it should just use the value of @item.Id. I have edited the question, can you check you are using the exact same code as I have now posted, including the hyperlink markup as well?

Comment: Sorry I meant edited my _answer_. Just double-check you have the same code as me. Actually I think the &amp is ok, it's just how the console is rendering &. That's a valid part of a querstring to separate the variables. The concern is why UserID is not populating, when you say the value is coming through from the textbox ok. I have tested this code myself and it appears to work.

Comment: @ADyson write this url = url.replace("USER_ID","12"); and work,but when write this url = url.replace("USER_ID", $("#USERID").val()); not work! click function write into the document.ready in jquery

Comment: ok so your textbox is the problem. Ensure you have a textbox on the same page which looks like this `<input type="text" id="USERID"/>`

Comment: change text box place and work,thanks a lot for pay attention to my problem and answer my friend.

Answer (score 1):

Textbox value is  dynamic. It depends on  user input. Razor tags are compiling at the server and posting to the client.So your razor code can not understand what user going to do to your text area. You need an action trigger the method that includes determining the text box values and send to the server. You can use ajax function.
With Jquery's help.

I think @item is a loop variable.
you can change your code like below

```
<a onClick="myFunction(@item.id)">@item.BookName</a>
```

as you see i catch the id and type down as a paramenter.
this is your text area

```
<input type="text" id="USERID"/>
```

this is the javascript function that gets the textbox value and sends it to your action

```
function myFunction(id){
    var userId = document.getElementById("UserID").value;
    var data ={
        parentPartId:id,
        UserID:userId
    }

    $.ajax({          //Jquery stuff
            url : '/Store/Item'
            type:'POST',
            data:data
            dataType:'json'
            success:function(){//You can handle succes scenario}
        });
}
```

See the data's structure it is a JSON object. And parameter names are same as your actions parameters. When you send it. MVC going to understand the logic and match the parameters and values. )

Comment: this doesn't directly reproduce the same behaviour - an ajax request is not the same as a redirect performed by clicking on a link. And if you're going to give an example requiring jQuery (the .ajax function), why not use jQuery syntax to declare the event handler? Inline events are generally considered bad practise, jQuery or not. Also, use URL.Action to ensure the correct URL is generated, otherwise it could be wrong depending on the MVC routing config and the setup on the deployed environment.

Comment: I edited my post about jquery. On the  other hand, I do not think there is a "generating" problem. Why would it be?.

Comment: like I said , there could be a problem if a different routing config is used than the default, or if the site is not deployed to the root folder of the IIS website / virtual directory. You can't assume that the formula for getting an Action's URL is always that simple. There are plenty of questions on SO where people have experienced problems with this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place form and post your data via model/Form collection

view code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveData", "TestCont", FormMethod.Post, new { Id = "frmTest", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="text" id="USERID" name="UserID"/>
}
```

controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult SaveData(FormCollection form)
{
    string html = Convert.ToString(form["UserID"]);
}
```

make sure to mark `[ValidateInput(false)]` otherwise it will raise error on posting html

You can place a submit button in form to post it, or in JavaScript use `$('#frmTest').submit()`

Comment: `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` is unnecessary here, it's only required if you are uploading files. And what is "FormCollection"? This method signature is different from the OP's example, and you are retrieving the UserID in a strange way, circumventing the MVC model binder for no apparent reason.

Comment: yes, this can be removed if you are not uploading any file

Comment: I'm not being petty, I just was pointing out that there are some things I don't think are right with the code, like the way you are bypassing the model binder and suppressing the built-in validation - why would you throw away valuable security and sanity-checking features which are built into the framework? There is nothing strange about this scenario which would justify that, it's a very standard situation of submitting some simple data.